# python str to tensorflow tf.string tensor

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to convert a python variable having str format into Tensorflow's Tensor with tf.string data type.
Anyone having an idea how to?

Here's what I tried, but it expects `data` is already in Tensor format.

```
print(type(data)) # <type 'str'>
myTensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(data, dtype=tf.string) # ERROR!
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce the error as follows:

```
myTensor = tf.convert_to_tensor("foo", dtype=tf.string) 

print(myTensor)
```

However the print output is Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string) so it seems to be working properly in my case.

I'm not sure why you would get an error.